# Compare XPATH text to string

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to assert true/false based on the text under this XPATH is equal to a string.

```
//div[@class='message au-board']
```

so

```
//div[@class='message au-board']/text()
```

Here is the code I have

```
el = (By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='message au-board']/text()]")
assert el == "AppleOrangeGrape"
```

Printing el gives: `('xpath', ".//div[@class='message au-board']/text()")`

In Dev Tools pasting "`.//div[@class='message au-board']/text()`" highlights the exact text I want to compare my string to: `AppleOrangeGrape`

Comment: Is this issue resolved? or post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
el = (By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='message au-board']/text()]")
```

You forgot the function name `find_element`.  Also there seems to be an extra `]` in that xpath.

```
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='message au-board']").text
```

Comment: Good catch, but
driver.find_element (By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='message au-board']").text
says AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element'

I have it imported: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: As far as I can see, `WebDriver` objects absolutely _do_ have a `.find_element()` method.  I have no idea what would cause that error.